# Kivy on_release not working on touchscreen - SDL issue?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, sdl, touchscreen

I have developed a basic app with Kivy but `on_release` does not work properly on my button bind.  I can get `on_press` to work every time but `on_release` works sporadically (maybe one in ten to twenty times) and sometimes on a different part of the screen than you've touched.

I'm pretty confident it's not a coding issue and one of the Kivy devs said it is not a known issue and should work but they haven't said where I might dig deeper.

In tandem with this, I have been receiving an SDL error in terminal:
`INFO: The key you just pressed is not recognized by SDL. To help get this fixed, please report this to the SDL forums/mailing list <https://discourse.libsdl.org/> EVDEV KeyCode 330`

This appears on both touch and release.  EVDEV advised to upgrade to SDL2, which I did and it has not solved the error which could just apparently be ignored if not for the spam it creates.

I'm not sure if these two issues are linked but don't know where to start with troubleshooting.

Can anyone please help with what steps I could follow to try and get this resolved?

I mostly want to fix `on_release` but if we fix the other error in the process then that would be great too.

I am running a Raspberry Pi Zero W, Raspbian Buster w/Desktop and a Hyperpixel 4.0 square screen

Comment: Does the SDL key error correlate with the button failures? And does this happen for all apps?

Comment: I have created a small test app for this and the problem persists so, yes, all apps. There is no correlation with the failures and the error. The error prints on both press and release every single time regardless. Thanks

Comment: Were you running the app via SSH, or directly via a keyboard connected to the Pi?

Comment: SSH, but the app was running on a connected touchscreen

Comment: Just revisiting this as I still don't have a solution.  The SDL error has actually got in the latest version of RPi OS, but still only sporadically getting on_release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the SDL error seemed to disappear in the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS (as opposed to Raspbian Buster).

The issue with on_release turns out to be an issue with Kivy's `[postproc:calibration]` settings in `/.kivy/config.ini`.  I am using settings there to invert the touch as my provider has inverted x,y coordinates.  The issue is that kivy doesn't seem to use the inversion settings for on_touch_up, only on_touch_down and therefore doesn't dispatch on_release.

[Issue raised on GitHub here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/7028)

Comment: This issue has annoyingly returned with the latest rpi OS

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem.  I am using Kivy 1.11.1 with SDL reporting as 2.0.9+dfsg1-1+rpt1 in dpkg.  I have read that this is fixed in a later SDL version but I've not worked out how to upgrade this.  Take care if you extract the SDL RPI tarball, as on my system it trashed the /usr permissions (and didn't upgrade the version as reported by dpkg).
If I run mtdev-test (see google), the touchscreen events come through smoothly.  When running kivy apps, the touchscreen events seem to be laggy, coinciding with the 330 error report.  Press/release seems to work, but motion events are erratic.
With my touchscreen, the error problem can be demonstrated really well with the kivy example demo/touchtracer, which works great with a USB mouse but is terrible with the touchscreen.

Comment: I upgraded to latest SDL and it didn't solve either the error or the release issue.  mtdev-test also shows all events for me but on_release doesn't work in Kivy

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had been seeing this behaviour with SDL2 2.0.10+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 amd64 and Kivy 2.1.0, but it turned out to be something simpler. I had buttons that were too small. This was creating some mismatched press/release events.